# How to load font permanently in blackberry app(font manager loads single time only) and it takes long time to load

Tags: blackberry

if (FontManager.getInstance().load("gautami.ttf", "gautami", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS)

```
        {
        try{

         _fontFamily1  = FontFamily.forName("gautami");//_fontFamily1 = FontFamily.forName("aerial");
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            _fontFamily1 = Font.getDefault().getFontFamily();
    }
     _headFont = _fontFamily1.getFont(Font.PLAIN,_size);

     super.setFont(_headFont);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the correct flag:

```
        int result = FontManager.getInstance().load("mtfont.ttf", "myfont", FontManager.SYSTEM_FONT); 
        // With the APPLICATION_FONT flag, the font is not available in system options and will be removed after exiting your app. However, it will be available during this time for others app to use.

        // Wit the SYSTEM_FONT flag, the font will be available in the system options, will be stored in persistent memory and will be reloaded on each reboot.
```